# Listar a última mensagem de cada usuário

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query, select

Alguém sabe como eu poderia listar a última mensagem de cada usuário?

Eu consegui fazer isso, mas lista a última mensagem de apenas um usuário, e eu queria que listasse de todos que mandaram mensagem para o usuário em questão(código 3).

```
SELECT m1.codigo,
       m1.codigo_remetente,
       usuario.url,
       m1.descricao,
       m1.data,
       m1.visualizado,
       usuario.nome,
       usuario.sobrenome
  FROM mensagens m1
  JOIN usuario ON m1.codigo_remetente = usuario.codigo
   AND m1.codigo_destinatario = 3
   AND data = (SELECT MAX(data)
                 FROM mensagens m2
                WHERE m2.codigo_remetente = m1.codigo_remetente)
 ORDER BY data DESC
```

Tabela Usuário: codigo, nome, sobrenome, url.

Tabela Mensagem: codigo, codigo_remetente, codigo_destinatario, descricao, data

Comment: Qual é a estrutura da tabelas `mensagem` e `usuario` no banco de dados?

Comment: Editei o post com as colunas das tabelas.

Comment: Tabela mensagem define a relação muitos para muitos entre dois usuários? Tem como explicar melhor o problema? Como seria esse "listasse todos que mandaram mensagem para o usuário"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `NOT EXISTS` para especificar que quer a última mensagem enviada para o usuário de código 3, como no exemplo, por qualquer usuário, contanto que não haja mensagem enviada posteriormente:

```
SELECT men.codigo,
       men.data,
       men.descricao,
       men.visualizado,
       men.codigo_remetente,
       usu.url,
       usu.nome,
       usu.sobrenome
  FROM mensagem men
       INNER JOIN usuario usu ON men.codigo_remetente = usu.codigo
 WHERE men.codigo_destinatario = 3
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM mensagem men2
                   WHERE men2.codigo_remetente = men.codigo_remetente
                     AND men2.codigo_destinatario = men.codigo_destinatario
                     AND men2.data > men.data)
 ORDER BY men.data DESC
```

> [**Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE

Ou em tradução livre:

> Se a subquery retornar qualquer linha, EXISTS será VERDADEIRO, e NOT EXISTS será FALSO

---

Gostaria de deixar aqui uma observação extra:

Apesar de, em teoria, utilizar o `ON` seja igual em questão de desempenhos a utilizar `WHERE`, é "socialmente" mais aceitável que você utilize a cláusula `ON` do `JOIN` apenas para vincular as tabelas. Para restringir resultados utilize o `WHERE` deixando sua `query` mais legível.